# convert 3 bytes to signed integer with python2

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, type-conversion

I am trying to convert 3 bytes to an signed integer.

on python3 I can simply do the following

```
s = bytearray.fromhex('fcffff')
print(s, int.from_bytes(s, "little", signed=True))
==-4
```

I thought in python2 I can just use the struct library. But since it needs 4 bytes I just added '00' at the end.

```
s = bytearray.fromhex('fcffff00')
print(struct.unpack('<i', s )[0])
== 16777212
```

so that the -4 comes out here I must apparently add ff, if I do this with a positive number it works with 00.

Can someone explain me how the rule for this works and how I implement this 'correctly' for python2?

Answer (score 0):

not a good solution, but works

```
barray = bytearray(4)
barray[0] = b[0]
barray[1] = b[1]
barray[2] = b[2]

int3 = struct.unpack('<i', barray )[0]

if int3 > 8388607:
    barray[3] = bytes.fromhex('ff')[0]
    int3 = struct.unpack('<i', barray )[0]


print(int3)
```